# How to reset private ethereum blockchain (Geth)?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I am running private ethereum blockchain using ethereum and now I want to reset the chain and delete all the contracts, transactions and logs and restart everything from block 0.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Run the private ethereum chain in a docker container... and then you can throw the container or its data and deploy it again in a matter of seconds
those are some examples of how to run a private chain with a docker

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-run-geth-from-a-docker-container-b6d30620ca74/

https://medium.com/@javahippie/building-a-local-ethereum-network-with-docker-and-geth-5b9326b85f37

https://medium.com/51nodes/build-a-minimal-quorum-network-90c59ec22226

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will install my new chain in docker container but how can I remove my existing chain?

Comment: @Ruchita what is the command you used to start geth? usually in the command, you write the Path (datadir) of where your blockchain data should be saved. like this: geth --datadir="/tmp/eth/60/01" -verbosity 6 --ipcdisable --port 30301

Comment: geth --datadir ~/chaindata/ --networkid 12345 --verbosity 3 --rpc --port 30304 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr "<private IP>" --rpccorsdomain "http://<private IP>:8080,  http://<private IP>:8000" --rpcapi "web3,eth,personal,net"  --preload "/home/ubuntu/scripts/mineWhenNeeded.js" --nodiscover  --gcmode archive  --allow-insecure-unlock > ~/myLogs/bcLogs.out 2>&1 &

Comment: if you look for the folder "ChainData" then you will find 2 folders inside it, if you delete them then everything will be removed and you will start again from block 0. that is what I remember from last time using geth local 2 years ago :) @Ruchita